# Objective C - Google Auto complete - Table View - First row and second rows are overlapping

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I am new to Objective C. I am using google autocomplete api for searching places and am using table view to display the results.

But first and second rows are merging. Can you please suggest what will be the issue?

```
 - (nullable NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ((_gmsAutocompletePredictions.count || _searchBar.text.length)   && section == 0) {
        return "Search Result";
    }
 }

   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return (_gmsAutocompletePredictions.count || _searchBar.text.length) ? 1 : 0;
  }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView     numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ((_gmsAutocompletePredictions.count || _searchBar.text.length)  && section == 0 ) {
        return _gmsAutocompletePredictions.count;
    }
   }

   - (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // CPTLocationSearchCell User defined class which implements     UITableViewCell
    CPTLocationSearchCell * cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CPTLocationSearchCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.primaryLabel.attributedText = _gmsAutocompletePredictions[indexPath.row].attributedPrimaryText;
    cell.secondaryLabel.attributedText = _gmsAutocompletePredictions[indexPath.row].attributedSecondaryText;
    return cell;

 }

 // I think the problem with this function
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSLog(@"heightForRowAtIndexPath %lu %lu     ",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);
         return 0.0;
     }
     return 60;
   }
```

Comment: Are you using custom tableview?

Comment: Yes I am using table view to display the results, @Rajesh .

Comment: show cellforrow code

Comment: @Rajesh I have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer . I just commented the if loop of "heightForRowAtIndexPath" and now it is working . thanks Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

Might be help follow this!

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

     if (_gmsAutocompletePredictions.count>0) {
        return _gmsAutocompletePredictions.count;
     }
     else
     {
        return 0; // or 1 pass when no record found
     }
     //return (_gmsAutocompletePredictions.count || _searchBar.text.length) ? 1 : 0;
}

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     if (_gmsAutocompletePredictions.count>0) {
          // CPTLocationSearchCell User defined class which implements     UITableViewCell
          CPTLocationSearchCell * cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CPTLocationSearchCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
          cell.primaryLabel.attributedText = _gmsAutocompletePredictions[indexPath.row].attributedPrimaryText;
          cell.secondaryLabel.attributedText = _gmsAutocompletePredictions[indexPath.row].attributedSecondaryText;
          return cell;
     }
     else
     {
         CPTLocationSearchCell * cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CPTLocationSearchCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
         return cell;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help